# Bug with typeof null in JS V8 engine

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8

It seems that JS [V8](https://developers.google.com/v8/) engine [has a bug](https://github.com/v8/v8/commit/7dfb5beeec8821521beeb2b8eac36707a663064c).

As example you can execute this script in the Chrome console (*I use version 51.0.2704.103 m.*) and each time you will get random (at first glace) number of true and false values:

```js
    function foo(){
        return typeof null === 'undefined';
    }
    
    for (var i = 0; i<1000; i++) console.log(foo());
```

For example:

[image]

On different OS / systems this bug appears on different iterations.

I realize that this question has little practical sense, but I wonder **what causes this strange behavior** and **depending on what changes the number of iterations**?

Also, what should be kept in mind when you write code using `typeof null` in case of this bug?

Comment: Just tried this in Chrome and I'm getting 1000 false's

Comment: The first time I run the loop, it happens for me as well (133 false, 867 true). Subsequent calls of the loop always yield 1000 true, though.

Comment: @robertklep Not if you redefine the function each time. Subsequent calls to the same function will print 1000× `true`…

Comment: @feeela yeah, redefining the function will always yield both true and false results.

Comment: Tried on 3x Windows PC (always random results) and 1x MAC (more consistent results, but still random).

Comment: @robertklep I consistently get the first 132 false `for (var i = 0; i<132; i++) foo();` and everything after that true

Comment: @user2314737 same on MAC, but after several tries count of false results changes.

Comment: @user2314737 same here, if I reopen new tabs tho, I get different random results

Comment: Node v6 also exhibits the same behaviour (random results). Node v4 doesn't. So my guess is that it's a recent V8 issue.

Comment: On my mac threshold is 12291. It and everything bellow it behaves normal but if 12292 then i get one true. Any consecutive call to function prints all true values. This is quite weird

Comment: I always get false returned, and I went up to 100,000 iterations. I'm using an old version of chrome though, version 49.0.2623.87 m.

Comment: For reference, it's an [already fixed bug](https://github.com/v8/v8/commit/7dfb5beeec8821521beeb2b8eac36707a663064c) in the V8 jitter.  Posting as a comment only, as I don't know enough about the innards to explain _why_ it's happening.

Comment: I've tried in chrome and got strange result, but the same thing works perfectly fine on node ( tried on version 5.10.1)